# Floats subtraction / addition - calculate loss of precision

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision

I am trying to wrap my mind around floating-point arithmetics and related loss of precision. I do understand that I can lose a lot of precision when I perform addition of big and small numbers (due to magnitude mismatch) or subtraction of nearly equal numbers (catastrophic cancellation). I was wondering if there is a way to calculate how many bits will I lose if I perform an addition or subtraction of 2 decimal numbers, i.e.:

**Given 2 decimal numbers** (or 2 numpy arrays of floats whose shapes match so element-wise comparison is possible) **how can I check how many bits of precision will I lose if I perform their subtraction of addition?**

Does the algorithm depend on the floating-point type in use, i.e. single precision vs double precision vs half precision (or numpy.float32, numpy.float64, numpy.float16)?

**EDIT - EXAMPLE**

Consider for instance a standard example of catastrophic cancellation. Let's assume you want to numerically assess the derivative of sin(x) at a point. You soon realise that even though theoretically the smaller the delta or h in the formula the more accurate the result, it does not hold if you assess the derivative numerically. Simply while assessing `f(x + h) - f(x)` you might run out of precision, i.e. `f(x + h)` will become equal to `f(x)` as the amount of representable numbers is finite. 
Here's some code:

```
import numpy as np

def get_sin_diff(point, max_idx, data_type=np.float32):
    """ Calculate: f(x + h) - f(x) as h varies. """
    smaller = np.sin(point, dtype=data_type)
    print("f(x) = {:.25f}".format(smaller))

    for idx in xrange(0, max_idx + 1):
        h = 10.0 ** (- idx)
        bigger = np.sin(point + h, dtype=data_type)
        diff = bigger - smaller
        print("h = {},\t f(x+h) = {:.25f},\t diff = {:.25f}".format(
            h, bigger, diff
        ))
```

(I assume single precision floating point format in the analysis.) So, if `h = 0.01` then you get the best result. You subtract `0.846831858158111572265625 - 0.841470956802368164062500= 0.005360901355743408203125` and you lose only 6 out of 23 bits of precision:

```
  0 01111110 1011 0001 1001 0011 1111 001
- 0 01111110 1010 1110 1101 0101 0100 100 
-----------------------------------------
  0 00000000 0000 0010 1011 1110 1010 101
```

From this point on the results degrade: if you choose `h = 0.0001` you loose 13 out 23 bits of precision:

```
  0 01111110 1010 1110 1101 1100 0101 111
- 0 01111110 1010 1110 1101 0101 0100 100
-----------------------------------------
  0 00000000 0000 0000 0000 0111 0001 011
```

If you choose `h = 1e-07` then you loose 21 out of 23 bits of precision and if you choose e.g. `h = 1e-08` you get 0 as there were no precision left.

So, my question is: **Given an addition of subtraction how do I assess how many bits of precision will I lose?** so I can detect where the results degrade too much. I can do that the hard way like I presented here but I think there is a formula to assess at least the lower and upper bounds.

Comment: You say "2 decimal numbers". Do you mean 2 floats, or do you actually have something represented in decimal?

Comment: Are you asking how much precision you will lose of the maximum amount you could lose? I assume the sizes and signs of the two numbers can be taken into account? And yet, the types used to store the two numbers and the result definitely matter.

Comment: Please include concrete examples, showing some inputs and the exact outputs you're expecting. (So that we don't have to guess how exactly you define "bits of precision" here.)

Comment: `small + big - big - small` might be a good starting point for computing the error in an addition (where `big` is the summand with the bigger magnitude). I think it might even be exact as long as the sum doesn't overflow, but I haven't proven it, and my tests haven't been very thorough.

Comment: @user2357112 By "2 decimal numbers" I mean what is displayed and stored (?) in a float in python as opposed to sth that is given in floating-point notation: `(-1) ** s * 1.f * 2 ** (e - bias)`. So for example: 100.23 - 0.0003 or 90.3458 + 1.9873.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I guess the types do matter when you decide on whether to continue with the operation or not (e.g. you lose 8 out of 23 bits available in single precision floating point numbers). Intuitively, I think that if you want to assess the number of bits that will be lost you must consider the signs and sizes, but I am not sure - that's what I'm asking about. :)

Comment: @NPE I included a detailed example. If you have any ideas on how to approach the problem I would highly appreciate your comments.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you for suggestion. I do not look for a way to reduce the error in subtraction or addition (i.e. sth like Kahan or Neumaier's summation) though. I want to detect the problem if & when it comes up. So e.g. I want to get an information that due to the given subtraction / addition I lost 6 bits of precision and decide what to do with that depending on the situation. But I do not want to run shadow computations neither (it is assess the same operation in higher precision & compare the results).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thank you for suggestions. I kind a already understand how to run the calculations on paper. I was wondering if there is a nice formula to assess how much bits or decimal digits (it's easy to move between those - it's just log10 of 2 to the number of bits in the significand) of precision I can lose if I decide to perform an operation.

Comment: @UserAnonymous: I'm not saying you should compute the error to compensate for it. Computing the error tells you exactly how wrong your calculation is. (Compensating for the error might be about as cheap as measuring it, though.)

Comment: Given your edit, you seem to be thinking of things from a different perspective, though. Catastrophic cancellation doesn't introduce error; the error comes from previous measurements or computations. You may want to compare the magnitude of the result to the magnitude of the larger operand of the subtraction.